# how to optimize table in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have one database and it contains 100 tables , in which three tables size are increase to 3 GB to 8 GB.what i do to reduce the table size.?
i am using optimize table command , it is working fine but size not decrease .

i am using percona tool kit command . 
commands are working fine and completed successfully but 
table size is same there is no effect on table size.
what will i do to solve this issue?

HOW I CAN OPTIMIZE TABLE WITH pt-online-schema-change for optimizing very large table?
my table size is 10 GB how can i decrease the table size.

Comment: Do you even know what you want to do and what you are doing?

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

If the data in your tables is already well organized on disk, optimize table won't help you.

You can:

- delete old data
- get rid of secondary indexes that you don't need
- turn on compression for your tables
- partition your tables and move certain partitions to other storage

Answer (score 0):

How to shrink disk footprint?

- Don't use `INT` (4 bytes) when `MEDIUMINT` (3 bytes) will suffice.
- Don't use `MEDIUMINT` when `SMALLINT` (2 bytes) will suffice.  Etc.
- Don't use utf8 for hex strings.
- Normalize repeated values.  (Within reason)
- Compress `TEXT` fields in the client, then use `BLOB`.
- Do not `PARTITION` unless there is a valid reason for it; it is likely to make the footprint bigger, perhaps significantly bigger.
- `INDEX(a)` is useless if you have `INDEX(a,b)`
- `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is likely to be a waste of time.  (As you found out.)

`pt-online-schema-change` (or 5.6) helps you make *certain* changes without locking the table a long time.

You have not even mentioned the basics -- MyISAM or InnoDB.  (Some techniques differ.)  Windows or Unix?  (Some tools do not work on Windows.)

Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; we can probably come up with more suggestions.

Why is 10GB scaring you?  Many systems deal with 100GB.  1TB gets a bit scary.